# Asp.net async/await Web API random slow

Tags: asp.net

We have a very simple async web api  defined as
public async Task> GetOrderById(long id).
Normally, it runs quickly and can be completed in 100ms. However sometimes, it takes more than 5 seconds on Production.
The following figure is one of the slow call we traced (The last column shows methods' offset time in ms when the server received the api call ). 
[image]

The 'RedisDataBase.StringGetAsync' method is called in AuthenticationAttribute class (subclass of ActionFilterAttribute), using the 'OnActionExecutingAsync' async way, by 'var user = await redisCache.TryGetAsync(sessionId)'.

So we suspects the API has been temp blocked during switching back to Asp.net thread after the 'await' keyword. After replacing the 'OnActionExecutingAsync' method with the 'OnActionExecuting' for AuthenticationAttribute class and sync call redis server, the cost can be eliminated.

Furthermore, we removed the AspNetSynchronizationContext inside the API to avoid unnecessary context switch as below

```
public async Task<ResultModel<OrderModel>> GetOrderById(long id)
    {
        var capturedContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        try
        {
            // Tricky, set current SynchronizationContext to null, to avoid capturing context during call await
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
            ...
            return new ResultModel<OrderModel>(order);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Restore the sync context
          SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(capturedContext);
        }
```

However at the end of callstack, sometimes, there is still a few seconds unknown cost. My question is what happened here? is there any article or direction I should do further investigation?
 [image]

BTW. currently in our project we are still mixing using async & sync webapi and most of api are still using sync. Is it the root cause for the performance issue?

And, We have monitored the PROD machine. It shows the thread number is around 120 and there is rare 'Requests Queued' number (8 at peak). Could it be caused by insufficient Asp.net thread pool number? We don't explicated setting the thread count in our application and web.config, and i was told the iis 8.0 default mode is auto can be dynamic adjust the thread pool number.

Comment: Can you post full source code of `GetOrderByAsync()`, or some parts where we can see what is going on inside.

Comment: var order = (await OrderServiceInstance.GetById(orderId)).ToOrderModel; 

We use AOP for OrderServiceInstance's method and check whether the order exists in Redis; if not, it will load data from DB via Entity Framework then cache the result in Redis.  
The latest Redis call before 'OutputCacheModule.OnLeave' is happened inside the OrderServiceInstance::GetById method.